# Given oauth client id/secret, is there a way to know which account it is defined in?

Tags: oauth2

We have used Salesforce oauth clientid/secret in one of the apps. We have multiple salesforce dev orgs and not sure in which devorg that oauth client/secret were created in.

Given client id and secret, is there any api which can give details about devorg where oauth app was created in?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no way at all to figure out which org a Connected App came from, even if you contact Support. That said, it wouldn't hurt to ask through more official channels. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I tried a while back with internal tools and couldn’t find a way to do it. Doesn’t mean it’s impossible but surely non-obvious!

Comment: Are you authorized with these credentials? I figure out, that if you have `id_token`, you can check `sub` property in jwt.io.

Comment: id_token represents the end user (username it returns is that of authorized user) so it will not give details about the connected app itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to directly trace the defining org for a connected app without opening a support case.

Raising a new idea exchange is the correct path if you would like to see this functionality in the future, although there could be complications around who owns those defining orgs and should you be granted that information.